# How to select range of values on same row as selected cell?

Tags: vba, excel

So I am using a search to find a value in Col1 (shown in the image below) and once I find that cell, I want to select all items in that row that are in Col3 and over that have values.

For example if my search is looking for val1, then I want to select num1, num2, and num3 into an array.

I have the search working to find the Address of the val, but I have not been able to figure out how to get all the values in Col3 and to the right that are not empty.

[image: my excel example]

Comment: Loop through range C to last column and if a value exists redim array +1 and add value

Comment: @Flephal, What is the best way to select the Row when I have the .Address I want of the cell in Col1?

Comment: You can use .Row for the found range.

Comment: Say you named the `.Address` Col1 then `Cells(Col1.row, 3)` or `Range("C" & Col1.row)` for the 3rd column, or define a long for it and reference that instead... Another option is create a Do Until Loop and do until x,y is blank.

Comment: @Flephal Would you be able to give a code snippet? When I call my rangeObject.Row I get a Type Mismatch.

Comment: What code have you tried already? Editing your question to show current code would help out

Answer (score 3):

This may help:

```
Sub SelectNumbers()
    Dim foundCell As Range, lastNum As Integer, nums As Range, arr() as variant, i As Integer

    Set foundCell = ActiveCell
    lastNum = foundCell.Offset(0, 2).End(xlToRight).Column

    //Get range object
    Set nums = Range(Cells(foundCell.Row, 3), Cells(foundCell.Row, lastNum))

    Debug.Print nums.Address

    //Read as array
    arr = Range(Cells(foundCell.Row, 3), Cells(foundCell.Row, lastNum)).Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        Debug.Print arr(1, i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am not sure how your code defines the cell you are searching for. In my code I have used `ActiveCell` as a surrogate. You will need to adapt this.

I have made two assumptions:

1. Your `nums` always start in column 3
2. Your `nums` are always contiguous i.e. no blank cells interspersed within `nums`

I also show how to get `range` object or `array`. You decide which you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

if a column is inserted between Col2 and Col3, Or the data structure is different, all you need to do is adapt the `foundCell.Offset(row, column).End(xlToRight).Column`

Just adding to Alex P's answer

> 2. Your `nums` are always contiguous i.e. no blank cells interspersed within nums

if Col3 can contain some empty spot, like this:

[image: empty values]

something like `Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` would be more suited to get last value of Col3 ( IF and Only IF Column 3 is the last column of your table )